# Descriptive naming conventions for Interfaces & Abstract Classes

Tags: c#, architecture, naming-conventions

I have recently been experimenting with naming abstract classes and interfaces in a more descriptive way. Mainly to try and ensure that they do not stray from their intended purpose.

So for abstract classes I have been using **IsA** or **IsAn** for interfaces **ICan** or **IPerform**

For example, instead of IOperationManager; ICanPerformOperationManagement

I find this reads better when looking at class.

Im sure Im not the first to think like this and was wondering if anyone has used any sort  descriptive naming convention for interfaces and abstract classes? Will it scale to large projects, or is it just adding confusion?

EDIT: Is this question too subjective!?

Comment: I tend to try to name interfaces as a description of what an object *IS*, and in your example would use `IOperationManager` over the other.

Comment: Maybe better suited for programmers.

Comment: "Is this question too subjective!?" If you have to ask... it probably is. I don't think this would suit Programmers either, though.

Comment: @asawyer I dont find that works, as multiple interfaces can be implemented. If every interface implies IS then a class IS multiple things

Comment: If you really like the ICan type of naming convention you can think about IDisposable. So instead of having ICanBeDeleted you would have IDeletable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it's about being short and descriptive, eliminating redundant terms in the name.

Personally don't see the need to include `Can` or `Perform` in an interface name, because the very use of an interface in the first place describes that - the properties and methods then describe *what* it should be able to do.  Think about it this way - would you have an `ICantPerform...` for types that *don't* implement the interface?  Of course not; the interface is either implemented or it's not there to begin with.

If the developer understands what an interface is, then they understand this.  If they don't; they shouldn't be using interfaces until they do.

It's the same with abstract types.  `IsA` or `IsAn` is again redundant, because as soon as a type inherits from it, the relationship is complete.  As Dr.Andrew says (+1 there) - the `Base` suffix is useful as it implies there is abstract behaviour there to be implemented (which fits nicely with the rest of the BCL too).

For me, `IOperationManager` makes sense; `ICanPerformOperationManagement` is clunky.

Answer (score 2):

Abtract classes I tend to append Base to it, for instance `ViewModelBase` or `NodeBase`.

For interfaces, I tend to describe the object, so `IOperationManager` as opposed to `ICanPerformOperationManagement`. That being said I have occasionally renamed an interface from the rather boring `IDrawable` to a more interesting `ICanBeDrawn`

Consider how developers will use the codebase though. If you are tying into intellisense and know you have a class called `OperationManager`, you would expect its interface to be `IOperationManager`. Few would guess at first attempt that they should start typing `I..C..a..n..P..e..` etc...

Comment: I tend to use BaseViewModel / ViewModelBase too but the problem is what if I need to add yet another class on top of that one? Is it going to be ViewModelBaseBase or ActualViewModelBase? So I just leave the Base away and call it ViewModel. If I need to know wheter some type is abstract or not it is pretty easy in any IDE

Comment: @ToniParviainen yes pinch of salt aka "some sensibleness" is needed when naming classes. Do it enough and you become a dab hand. Then you find someone else in your team that disagrees. Lol. Personally I would have `ViewModelBase` but then say a derived (but still abstract type) as `SomeSpecificFunctionalityButStillAbstractViewModel`. All vms must inherit from `ViewModelBase` but not all from `SomeSpecificFunctionalityButStillAbstractViewModel`. There is no right way though. In conclusion just do what works